# Rotating UITextView programmatically

Tags: swift, cgaffinetransform

There is a weird problem, if you create a `UITextView` and rotate it right after creating it, some lines or characters will not be visible! Try this:

```
myTextView.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(20)
myTextView.text = "Hello world wht the hell\nhello mrs lorem ipum!"
let maxsize = CGSizeMake(700, 700)
let frame = myTextView.sizeThatFits(maxsize)
myTextView.frame = CGRectMake(200, 200, frame.width, frame.height)     
view.addSubview(myTextView)
myTextView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI_2))
```

Result: 
[image]

You see? most of is lost! But if you `remove myTextView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI_2))` and run it through a button it's fine:

[image]

You can view the code on git: https://github.com/maysamsh/rotateTextView

Comment: That's really weird ... You have the code up somewhere ?

Comment: @SamhanSalahuddin https://github.com/maysamsh/rotateTextView

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a workaround, try to set your `UITextView` in another simple `UIView`, and then rotate this `UIView`.

It should help because this way, `UITextView` should react like it's not rotated (so you can set it with inset constraints to superview)

Then you just have to care about the form of the superview.

*Other solution*

```
myTextView.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(20)
myTextView.text = "Hello world wht the hell\nhello mrs lorem ipum!"
let maxsize = CGSizeMake(700, 700)
let frame = myTextView.sizeThatFits(maxsize)
myTextView.frame = CGRectMake(200, 200, frame.width, frame.height)     
view.addSubview(myTextView)
let delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(0.1 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {  
    myTextView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI_2))
}
```

A bit dirty, but should work, the user might see a small clipping, but mostly he shouldn't even see it.

Comment: Because I have multiple UITextView with gestures attached to them, I can't use this method.

Comment: I don't see what's blocking you, you can do multiple view too and manage the gesture anyway.

Comment: It was just a part of my whole code. Trust me, I can't use this :P

Comment: Tricky answer, thanks. Let's see will be any other solution or not.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this again

```
var myTextView = UITextView() as UITextView
    myTextView.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(20)
    myTextView.text = "Hello world wht the hell\nhello mrs lorem ipum!"
    let maxsize = CGSizeMake(700, 700)
    let frame = myTextView.sizeThatFits(maxsize)

    myTextView.frame = CGRectMake(200, 200, frame.width, frame.height)
    self.view.addSubview(myTextView)


    let newframe = myTextView.sizeThatFits(frame)
    let ration = newframe.width/newframe.height
    myTextView.frame = CGRectMake(200, 200, ration*newframe.height, newframe.width)
    myTextView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI_2))
```

Comment: It's just the same as the first picture!

Comment: You need as 2nd picture. Right?