# The text in UITextView is being cutoff when rotated

Tags: ios, uikit, uitextview, cgaffinetransform

I am trying to allow the user to rotate text they place on a view inside UITextViews. The problem is when I rotate them using the transform property, the text gets cutoff. However, when I do this with UILabels, it works fine, so why not UITextViews? The bounds of UITextView (shown in green) never changes, so I am not sure why this is happening. The amount of cutoff seems related to the height of the text view.

[image: example on iPad]

The only work around I've found is to do the transform asynchronously. I don't know why it works, but I don't think it's a good solution. You can see this in action with the following code.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        for xPos in stride(from: 80, to: view.bounds.width, by: 80) {
            let point = CGPoint(x: xPos, y: 100)
            let textView = makeTextView(at: point)

            //DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let angle = xPos / 400.0
                textView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: angle)
            //}

            view.addSubview(textView)
        }
    }

    private func makeTextView(at point: CGPoint) -> UITextView {
        let textView = UITextView()
        textView.text = "1234567890"
        textView.isScrollEnabled = false
        textView.backgroundColor = .green
        textView.center = CGPoint(x: point.x, y: point.y)
        textView.bounds.size = CGSize(width: 80, height: 24)
        return textView
    }
}
```

What is the correct way to rotate them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rotating UITextView programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32304605/rotating-uitextview-programmatically)

Comment: Thanks, but that one only discusses workarounds which I am currently using (async transform). I still don't understand why text view behaves differently and needs these hacky solutions. Unless there really isn't another way...

Comment: It seems like applying CGAffineTransform to UITextView can break autolayout of its UITextContainerView subview so its frame doesn't match it parent and you see the cropped text. I believe that wrapping your UITextView in UIView is the easiest you can do to fix it.

Comment: So from what I understand, I'm not doing anything wrong per se, but there's a bug with the container view that *requires* a workaround solution. So I was mainly wondering if I was just doing this incorrectly, since for other views I didn't have to do this.

Comment: Right, what you're doing looks correct, after making some research I can say that many people complain that rotation of UITextView doesn't work as expected. However I'd recommend wrapping it to UIView rather than performing rotation asynchronously on the next loop run.